# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de convertir un double en un float con dos decimales?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de entender cuál es la mejor forma de convertir un resultado `double` en un `float` con dos decimales o, en su defecto, hacerlo de alguna forma. Explico:

Tengo las dos siguientes variables que lleno con información de acuerdo a lo obtenido de tres input que tengo en mi aplicativo:

```
double B2 = 0, B3 = 0, B4 = 0;
B2 = Double.parseDouble(sueldo_input.getText().toString());
B3 = Double.parseDouble(gastos_hogar_input.getText().toString());
B4 = Double.parseDouble(gastos_hormiga_input.getText().toString());
double db_saldo_final, db_porcentaje_deseado;

db_saldo_final = B2 - (B3+B4);
db_porcentaje_deseado = (B2*20)/100;
```

El resultado, por ejemplo, de `db_saldo_final` y `db_porcentaje_deseado` es algo como:

```
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 10000.0
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 7000.0
```

Lo que necesito es que estas dos variables me salgan así:

```
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 10000.00
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 7000.00
```

O en su defecto si la operación resultara con decimales fuera igual truncado a dos decimales como:

```
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 8596.72
db_porcentaje_deseado  = 5963.33
```

Estuve intentando lo siguiente encontrado en una pregunta similar pero no me funciona:

```
float fl_saldo_final = (float) (Math.round(db_saldo_final*100.00) / 100.0);
float fl_db_porcentaje_deseado = (float) (Math.round(db_porcentaje_deseado*100.00) / 100.0);
```

Pero lamentablemente el resultado sigue siendo el mismo que mi problema principal. Gracias.

Comment: si la variable es de tipo float, no vas a poder obtener dos decimales cuando no tenga decimales, en todo caso estas intentando imprimirlo con 2 decimales y no necesitas un float sino un String con 2 decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El double lo conviertes en float:

```
 double d= 10000.0
 float f = (float) d;
```

Cuentas los decimales, convirtiendo el double en String:

```
 Double de = d;
 String[] splitter = de.toString().split("\\.");
```

Usa DecimalFormat para agregar solo 2 decimales o quitar (truncar a 2):

```
 DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");  
 DecimalFormat format2 = new DecimalFormat("#");  
 format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
 format2.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Con if/else selecionas:

```
 if(splitter[1].length()==1) {
  textView.setText(String.valueOf(format.format(f)));

  }else if(splitter[1].length()>=3){
  textView.setText(String.valueOf(format2.format(f)));

  }else{
  textView.setText(String.valueOf(f));
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido muy bien. ¿Esta es la mejor forma para convertir de un double a un float de acuerdo a tu experiencia? Tengo como un año programando en java y sigo aprendido, gracias.

Comment: @FernandoTorres no se si sea la mejor, solo conozco esta forma. Saludos